# How can I specify delimiters for a VueJS component with a render method?

Tags: vuejs2

I have a `vuejs` `webpack-simple` project generated via `vue-cli`. However, I'm unable to set the delimiters when using the `render` function to render my `App` component:

```
new Vue({
  delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

If I don't use the `render` method, the `delimiters` are set correctly:

```
new Vue({
  delimiters: ['[[', ']]'],
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      // something
    }
  }
})
```

How can I specify the `delimiters` for a Vue component when using the `render` method?

Comment: It's working here https://jsfiddle.net/943bx5px/30/

Answer (score 4):

The `delimiters` option only sets the delimiters for the component it is specified for and will not affect the children. Currently, you are specifying that the root Vue instance should have `delimiters` set to `['[[', ']]']`, and then passing the `App` component definition to the `render` function without specifying a `delimiters` option for the `App` component.

If you're trying to set the delimiters just for the App component, then you'll need to do that wherever you are defining that component:

```js
const App = {
  template: `<div>[[ message ]]</div>`,
  delimiters: ['[[',']]'],
  data() {
    return { message: 'Hello' }
  }
}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

If you want to set the `delimiters` for every component, you can do that with a global mixin:

```js
Vue.mixin({ delimiters: ['[[',']]'] });

const App = {
  template: `<div>[[ message ]]</div>`,
  data() {
    return { message: 'Hello' }
  }
}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to set up global custom delimiters but it's not working. What should I check to figure it out? Thanks!

Comment: Okay, I found component's code is called before app's code, maybe it's a reason, maybe not (I have a component in a vue file).

Comment: hey @mimic, hard to help without seeing any of your code. I'd suggest posting a new question with a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your issue.

Comment: the code is pretty much the same, the only difference is I use .vue files as recommended Vue's documentation, and custom delimiters work everywhere except those components in vue files.

Comment: thanksd, I've created a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52409448/custom-delimiters-dont-work-for-components-in-vue-files can you please look at it? Thanks!!