# How to add global delimiters only once to make it work with all components?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using a Flask and want to replace the standard Vue delimiters to anything else. I found the following solution here: [How can I specify delimiters for a VueJS component with a render method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48143121/how-can-i-specify-delimiters-for-a-vuejs-component-with-a-render-method)

I was trying to add this code:

```
Vue.mixin({
    delimiters: ['[[', ']]']
});
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I have my components in .vue files. I found that the  following code in components is called before any Vue.mixin added:

```
export default {...}
```

Maybe it's a reason. The new delimiters work only for the main app, but not for components.

The Vue version is 2.5.17. Thanks.

Comment: where did you call `Vue.mixin({
    delimiters: ['[[', ']]']
});`? in `main.js` before call `new Vue({})`?

Comment: @Sphinx, yes, I call it before "var app = new Vue({...})" and it affected only main app itself, but not components. Also, I found right now that even adding delimiters into a component default extend not working at all.

Comment: Can't reproduct the issue. check [this fiddle with Vue 2.5.17](https://jsfiddle.net/2h8bm7j9/), it seems work fine. Can you post out the codes in `main.js`?

Comment: @Sphinx this code is not the same as mine. I have a piece of code looking similarly. It stops working as soon as I define a component in a vue file. Maybe it's a reason? If so, how can it be solved (not globally, just for components?)