# Custom delimiters don't work for components in .vue files

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, delimiter

I'm trying to use Flask with Vuejs. To keep constant style I want to set up other delimiters than curly brackets.

In main app file, before even defining app I use the code:

```
Vue.mixin({
    delimiters: ['[[', ']]']
});
```

It works for every app and components except those that are defined in .vue files. Even if I use the same code inside component's code in .vue file it spreads everywhere except that component:

```
<script> 
    import Vue from 'vue';
    Vue.mixin({ delimiters: ['[[',']]'] }); // tried it, no result
    export default {
        name: 'testComponentInVueFile',
        //delimiters: ['[[', ']]'], // tried it too, no result
        data: function(){
        ...
        }}
        ...
</script>
```

Version is 2.5.17.
What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: why u redefine the delimiters within your component? you don't need to do that because you have already defined it within your main js file. i think that you should define the delimiter within double quote

Comment: @Thamerbelfkih I know that I don't need them, but nothing worked so I tried different ways. Updated the code.

Comment: @Thamerbelfkih didn't get about quotes. Does it make any difference?

Comment: you imported your component within the main js file please? and imported it to Vue instance ? with  Vue.component ?

Comment: check [Vue guide: delimiters](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#delimiters), it states this: `Restrictions: This option is only available in the full build, with **in-browser** compilation.`

Comment: @Sphinx sorry I don't understand what it means. Can you explain?

Comment: check [Vue Author reply](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/5697#issuecomment-302302162); Delimiters can only be changed when using runtime compilation with the full build (vue.js). It does not work in `*.vue files` (to keep all `*.vue files` syntax consistent)

Comment: @Sphinx But this approach *doesn not* keep all code consistent. Because I have to redefine all the Vue code for those cases when used with server-side compilation to avoid the conflict, and then I have to use usual delimiters in .vue files. It just doesn't make any sense to me. If I could do it globally only once, it would keep all .vue files consistent. What they have done is opposite :((((

Comment: that is why **Vue guide** states that **restrictions** (only available in ful build with **in-browser** compliation, **one scenario**: in the fiddle, load full vue.js from cdn by `<script>`).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57407615/how-to-change-vue-clis-delimiters/57408145#57408145