# How to change vue-cli's delimiters?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-cli

I installed vue-cli (webpack-simple)

**src/main.js**:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

new Vue({
  delimiters: ['?{', '}'],     // here , delimiters set " ?{ } " 
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

Above code is not working (`?{}`), `{}` keeps working

**/src/App.vue** code changing

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    ?{ msg }
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "app",
  delimiters: ["?{", "}"], // here , delimiters set " ?{ } " 
  data() {
    return {
      msg: "Welcome to Your Vue.js App"
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

**index.html** (not working):

```html
<div>  ?{ msg }  </div>
```

I want to print 'Welcome to Your Vue.js App"

help me

Thank You!!

Answer (score 4):

See the response from the Author:

> Delimiters can only be changed when using runtime compilation with the full build (vue.js). It does not work in *.vue files (to keep all *.vue files syntax consistent)

[Vue 2.5.1 Component custom delimiter not working #5697](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/5697#issuecomment-302302162)

---

[2020/07/03]

How to config to use runtime compiler to use custom delimiters

1. Create a `vue.config.js` file at your project root(the place you store `package.json`)
2. Add the content as follow:

```
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  runtimeCompiler: true
}
```

3. Delete `<template />` at `app.vue`
4. Modify the `<script />` at `app.vue` as follow:

```
// app.vue
<script>
export default {
    delimiters: ['{', '}'],
    name: 'App',
    template: '<div id="app">{ title }</div>',
    data () {
        return {
            title: 'This is a Title'
        };
    }
};
</script>
```

5. The document [Configuration Reference#runtimeCompiler](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#runtimecompiler)

Comment: how to change delimiters in vue-cli complie ?

Comment: then can you write a little example