# Changing Vue delimiters

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, delimiter

So I'm doing a web app using flask and vue and I want to change vue delimiters to `{$` and `$}` but I'm having some trouble making it work.

I'm using a multi-page setup for vue and using flask as a route.

**What I tried:**

Inside main.js adding delimiters in new Vue but doesn't seem to work:

```
new Vue({
  render: (h) => h(Index),
  delimiters: ['{$', '$}'],
}).$mount('#app');
```

also tried adding
`Vue.config.delimiters = ['{$', '$}'];`
inside main.js but didn't work

**-- CODE --**

main.js file:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Index from '@/components/index.vue';

Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.config.delimiters = ['{$', '$}'];

new Vue({
  render: (h) => h(Index),
}).$mount('#app');
```

HelloWorld.vue:

```
<h1>{$ msg $}</h1>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  props: {
    msg: String,
  },
};
</script>
```

index.vue:

```
<HelloWorld msg="INDEX FROM VUE"/>
<script>
import HelloWorld from '@/components/HelloWorld.vue';

export default {
  name: 'index',
  components: {
    HelloWorld,
  },
};
</script>
```

Directory map:

[image]

So basically instead of outputting the message is outputting `{$ msg $}

Comment: what doesn't work? also is it `{$$}`, `{%%}` or `${}` you're trying a few

Comment: @LawrenceCherone sorry about that. The ones i want are `{$$}`.
Did some modification to the post. Hope it helps

Comment: I may be missing something too, I just checked[*](https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-visvesvaraya-pu27) and does not seem to work either by placing in main.js or directly on the component. Also tried various ways thinking it dont like `$`.. nutting

Comment: It does say in docs, *This option is only available in the full build, with in-browser compilation.* whatever that means.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone so should I build and try? I'm confused!

Comment: imo it should work without building else how would one develop it, it is confusing as on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-visvesvaraya-pu27l) it somewhat compiles it and does not work at all but works when not built on [playcode](https://playcode.io/624391/) only if added to each component. sorry im not sure how to solve this one :(

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57407615/how-to-change-vue-clis-delimiters/57408145#57408145